# Get Edges between Vertices (outer polygon)

Tags: math, three.js, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm using THREE.JS and I have a this mesh with different surfaces. Of each surface I got its vertices. Now I want to create edges ( connect the vertices with lines). The vertices are in an arbitrary order, so I can't simply connect v1 with v2, v2 with v3 and so on. I think I have to walk through them with a ray clockwise or counter clockwise and put them in the right order somehow and I have to somehow check their distances, so that the horizontal line between the inner vertices doesn't appear, rather it should go right along the real edges,but I don't know how... Any idea?

(the spheres are the vertices that are the real corners of the surface, the orange lines are the wrong edges that need to be corrected and the blue lines are the edges of each single face)
[image]

I need to create these 8 edges  (red)
[image]

Comment: Please describe precisely what information is available.

Comment: I got information  about the faces' (the blue triangles) vertices and normals, 
and I got the position of the corners of all surfaces ( in this case the 8 corners ( here with spheres at its position at the brown surface)

Comment: What "information" ? Be specific.

Comment: If you don't know the order of the vertices, I don't see how you can do this in a general case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - with regard to the faces,  I got all their 3 vertices (positions), normals and IDs.

SURFACES: I check for faces with the same normals and wether they are adjacent to one another - if so, their IDs are added to an array (So for every surface there's an array). I programmed it the way that when I click a face, it searches in the surfaces arrays for their ID, and colors all faces in that array.

CORNERS: I get them through 
1. create array of all faces' vertices of a surface
2. check whole mesh's vertices - if they intersect a face of the surface -> add them to the array

Comment: I am not asking you how you process the data. I am asking you what information is available initially. Sorry to insist, this is required to answer your question.

Comment: But I'm telling you:
"with regard to the faces, I got all their 3 vertices (positions), normals and IDs."

Comment: Are the vertices known by coordinates or by an index to a table of coordinates ? If no, are the coordinates of the common vertices exactly equal ? Are the normals coherently oriented ? Are the triangles of a face perfectly coplanar ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to assign a unique number to the vertices and to uniquely associate every triangle to a face, and that the triangulation is watertight, the edges of a face are those edges that are common to a triangle of that face and a triangle of another. When you have all edges of a face, it is a trivial matter to chain them in a polygon.